Parameter inside SQL Transformation not working properly
Insert query with bind variable is not working in sql transformation when it is parameterized.
insert into abc (a, b, c) 
values (?a?,?b?,?c?)

I am calling the above query in a parameter file. Parameter name:$$insertquery. I have used the parameter directly inside sql transformation. Tried giving $$insertquery and '$$insertquery' inside sql transformation but it's not working.
Then I stored param value into a output port and then added the port "insert_query" into sql transformation, and called it in string substitution as ~insertquery~. Now substitution is happening but getting the error "invalid host/bind variables".
When I give the query directly its working. What could be the issue?

Could you [edit] your question and add more details? In particular, what do you mean by "not working"? What happens when you run your code how, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

By not working , I mean the informatica session is failing with the error ORA-01745 - invalid host/bind variables. When I run the code, I expect for the insert query to work and insert the records, and if i put the query directly in SQL transformation it is working. But when I parameterize i am getting the above error.
